# postgres database user grants to query database owned by other user

Tags: postgresql

The `postgres` learning curve is very steep for me I need help. (I come from a mysql background and have the bad habit of trying to translate my mysql knowledge to pg)

here is the premise:

- I want to import a sql dump of a `pg` database into a new (clean) instance.
- I want to have 2 users:

  - `dba` which will own the database and be able to do DDL.
  - `app` will be only able to `SELECT`, `INSERT`, `DELETE` and that sort of things.

With the research I did this is what I tought should work:

I `psql -U postgres` and do the following

```
CREATE ROLE "app" WITH ENCRYPTED PASSWORD '${APP_PASSWORD}' LOGIN;
CREATE ROLE "dba" WITH ENCRYPTED PASSWORD '${DBA_PASSWORD}' LOGIN;

REVOKE ALL ON SCHEMA public FROM PUBLIC;

GRANT ALL ON SCHEMA public TO "dba";

GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, TRUNCATE, REFERENCES ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO "app";
GRANT EXECUTE ON ALL FUNCTIONS IN SCHEMA public TO "app";
GRANT SELECT, USAGE ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA public TO "app";

ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR USER "dba" IN SCHEMA public GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, TRUNCATE, REFERENCES ON TABLES TO "app";
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR USER "dba" IN SCHEMA public GRANT EXECUTE ON FUNCTIONS TO "app";
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR USER "dba" IN SCHEMA public GRANT SELECT, USAGE ON SEQUENCES TO "app";
```

Then I login with `dba` and do

```
CREATE DATABASE "mydb";
```

Then I import my sql dump with psql

```
psql -U dba -c mydb < dump.sql
```

Then I see my data and tables with the user `dba`.

With the user `app` tho, I can connect with psql to `mydb` but when I do `\dt` I don't see my tables and a select returns:

```
mydb=> select * from mytable limit 10;
ERROR:  relation "mytable" does not exist
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your app user should be created like this.

### Create the user:

```
CREATE ROLE "app" WITH ENCRYPTED PASSWORD '${APP_PASSWORD}' LOGIN;
```

## Run this on mydb database.

### Grant Connect to DB:

```
GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE mydb to app;
```

### Grant Usage:

```
GRANT USAGE ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA public TO "app";
GRANT USAGE ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO "app";
```

### Grant Other privileges:

```
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, TRUNCATE, REFERENCES ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO "app";
GRANT EXECUTE ON ALL FUNCTIONS IN SCHEMA public TO "app";
```

Comment: update: `=> \dt public.*` returns my table... `=> select * from mytable limit 1;` gives: `ERROR:  relation "mytable" does not exist`. `SELECT * FROM public.mytable LIMIT 1;` returns : `ERROR:  permission denied for schema public`. @SQLadmin why do I need to add `public.` ? Can I set things up so I don't have to do this?

Comment: finally if I do your commands with `psql -U postgres -d tempalte1` it works ! If you update your reply I'll accept it

Comment: Vinni, Answer updated, you have to execute the Grant commands on the mydb. So it'll work. I forgot to mention this earlier, 
tempalte1 is not a good way to grant statements.